# port open in firewall but still blocked

Tags: iis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm building my first IIS platform. I have successfully opened ports for my first installs. I now want to open port 995 for a small app to POP gmail (on port 995). I have opened it in the firewall as per previous attempts. However connection is failing. If I view all open ports with [netstat -a] 995 is not included. Can I ask what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to talk out on port 995 to gmail. So, that port will only show in use on your computer while the connection is open. If its not open it wont show on the list.

If you were expecting incoming requests, then yes, the port would be expected to show in netstat while it waits for connectios.

Comment: thank you for that. A bit of a red herring. However I still have the basic problem. I opened 995 in same way as other successful openings, but I'm not getting out

Comment: Are you sure there are no other firewalls involved? When you monitor the firewall are you seeing it go through ?

Comment: I've spoken to my ISP who say there is no Firewall around my box. Is there a chance that there is another running somewhere on my machine? How do I see it going through?

Comment: Well, that depends on the firewall - see all this is so vague! How are you sure you're not getting out, and not maybe failing to authenticate etc?

Comment: First up, thanks for putting up with my learning curve! So I guess I need to check the port is open right? Telnet 995 or some other approach?